# Will MongoDB provide cursors to multiple clients (named cursors)?

Tags: mongodb, cursor, named

I am running several NodeJS instances on separate compute engines all accessing the same MongoDB. In each instance I am running a background housekeeping process which scans the entire customer collection in the database. I am using cursors to access documents, fetching the next customer one by one.

This yields a number of competing housekeeping processes, all wanting to access the same documents (customers) in the same order.

What I am looking for instead, is for my housekeeping processes to cooperate rather than compete.

So if I had two instances I could construct two opposite direction cursors. But if I have 3 or more instances or if I want to be tolerant to any number of instances going up and down without duplicating or phantoming customers, I need to find a different approach.

I was thinking, does MongoDB provide cursors addressable by name from multiple NodeJS instances such that all instances fetch the next document from the same cursor, never obtaining the same document?

If not, can anyone suggest a good pattern to apply to this problem?

Comment: I would suggest having your NodeJS instances split up the data they process using some indexed key. So, one instance only processes customers with username A-F, and so on. To add to this, sharding can give better performance benefits, but then that decision really depends on the data workload you have.

Comment: Thank you, but splitting data means I'd have to re-split data if any instance comes up or goes down. What I'm really looking for is a singleton cursor managed by MongoDB.